# Add a max width to legend in Highcharts

Tags: css, highcharts, legend

I created a column chart with an horizontal ***middle left legend***.

But with this configuration (horizontal + middle + left), the chart is almost not visible.

The legend should be wrapped instead of taking all the available place.

A solution would be to set a **max width** to the legend. But how can I do that ?

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/zjp8m60w/

```
    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        layout: 'horizontal', 
        floating:false,
    }
```

Thank you !

Comment: what is expected output? any visuals?

Answer (score 2):

What about changing to align them vertically, so they don't overlay the graph. With the `itemWidth` parameter you can set the width of the labels.

```
legend: {
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    floating:false,
    itemWidth: 80,
    floating: false,
    layout: 'vertical'
}
```

Updated [JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p23wowxz/1/)

---

Horizontal alignment with word-wrap

```
legend: {
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    floating: false,
    width: 175,
    layout: 'horizontal',
    itemStyle : '{ "word-wrap": "break-word"}'
}
```

See [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8dn4bqd2/)

Comment: Yes of course, it works with a vertical alignment, but what I need is to make it works with an horizontal alignment :)

Comment: Your example works with those legend labels, but if the legend are shorter, the legend will still be 160px wide, whereas I would like the legend to be less wide. This is why i wanted to use a maxwidth.

Comment: If you don't set a width on the legend, you'll see that the chart will be compacted on the right.... it should be the opposite... the chart should be drawn in a correct size, and the legend should take the available space. Right ?

Answer (score 1):

The examples above are a fixed width (rather than max width).  You can achieve a max character width like so:

```
labelFormatter: function () {
            const newName = this.name.substring(0, Math.min(this.name.length, 22));

            return newName.length === this.name.length ? newName : newName + "...";
        },
```

This goes inside the legend settings.

Comment: Note that labelFormatter is in legend directly(not in Settings):legend:{ labelFormatter: function () {} }